# Why does Visual Studio lag when working with some ASP.NET sites?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am working with an ASP.NET website that is currently being referenced by IIS. When I open .aspx files for editing, the pages seem to hang randomly - has anyone else experienced this? Is there a known cause (and solution)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem but maybe another cause.
If you use GIT in your visual studio, turn of "Show current branch in Visual Studio".
All of my lag went away in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

Something that seems to exacerbate this problem is non-compliant markup, but it can often happen with control libraries and also happens occasionally with the vanilla controls for no apparent reason.

You might want to change the default to "source view" rather than "design view". You can do this, in:

```
Tools >> Options >> Html Designer >> Start pages in
```